# Cardinality in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, cardinality

I have a UML diagram of what I need my database schema to look like. This diagram includes roles and cardinality. How can I enforce cardinality in Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cardinality is enforced by using [constraints.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html)

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html

Comment: Could you please give me an example of such a constraint?

Comment: What kind of cardinality are you trying to constrain? Range, uniqueness (another kind of range), or one-to-many joins? The link I provided has good examples of all three.