# How can i display seller's products on seller profile page?

Tags: php, magento

I am building a multi-seller marketplace on magento with a third party extension that shows a seller's profile page, details and reviews but it does not show seller's products.

How can I show seller's products on the sellers profile page?

This is the seller profile.phtml code:

```
<?php
$seller = $this->sellerProfile();
$country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode($seller['country']);
?>

<div class="seller-profile">
<div class="seller-top-panel">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="seller-profile-image">
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('marketplace')->getImagePath($seller['image']); ?>" height="140"     width="140">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="shop-info">
            <div class="shopname">
                <h2><?php echo $seller['shop_name']; ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="shop-description">
                <p><?php echo $seller['shop_description']; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="shop-contact">
                <span><?php echo $this->__('<b>Phone</b>: %s',$seller['telephone']);?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="seller-profile-contact">
                <span><?php echo $this->__('<b>Email</b>: %s',$seller['email']); ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="shop-location">
                <span><?php echo $this->__('<b>Country</b>: %s',$country->getName());?></span>
            </div>
            </li>

        <li class="summary-overview">
            <h3><?php echo $this->__('Rating Conclusion') ?></h3>
            <?php foreach($this->ratingOverview() as $rate):?>
                <div class="rating-list">
                    <?php $ratingName =  $this->getRatingName($rate['rating_id']); ?>
                    <?php $avgPercentage = ($rate['sub_total']*100)/($rate['rating_count']*5); ?>
                    <?php $rating = $rate['sub_total']/$rate['rating_count'] ; ?>
                    <?php $ratingTitle = $this->__("Rating: ").round($rating,1)."of 5"; ?>
                    <div class="rating-stars">
                        <div class="blank-stars"></div>
                        <div title="<?php echo $ratingTitle; ?>"class="fill-stars" style="width:<?php echo round    ($avgPercentage,2); ?>%"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rating-name"><?php echo $ratingName; ?></div>
                </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>        
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php $sum = 0;foreach($this->getReviewStars() as $rate) $sum += $rate['value_count'];?>
            <?php $positive = array(5,4); $rate = $this->getPositivePercentage($positive);?> 
            <div class="rating-linegraph">
                <div class="avgRatingSection sellerrating">
                    <?php $positiveTotal = count($rate) == 0 ? 0 : ($rate['positive_total']/$sum)*100 ?>
                    <div class="rating-percentage">
                        <span class="positive-average"><?php echo round($positiveTotal)."%"; ?></span> 
                        <span class="positve-label"><?php echo $this->__('Positive') ?></span>
                        </div> 
                        <span><?php echo $this->__('Based on %d ratings',$sum) ?></span>
                    </div>
                <div class="seller-rating-bar seller-rating">
                    <ul>
                    <?php $count=5;for($count=5;$count>=1;$count--):
                        $rate =  $this->getReviewStar($count);

                        $avg = ($rate == null ? 0 : (($rate['value_count']/$sum)*100));
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <span><?php echo $count.$this->__('star') ?> </span>
                            <div class="blank-ratingbar">
                                <div class="fill-bar" style="width:<?php echo $avg;  ?>%"></div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="rate-vote"><?php echo $rate == NULL ? 0 : $rate['value_count']; ?    ></span>
                        </li>
                <?php endfor; ?>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="seller-rate-type seller-rating">
                    <div class="border type-positive"><?php echo $this->__('Positive'); ?></div>
                    <div class="border type-neutral"><?php echo $this->__('Neutral');?></div>
                    <div class="border type-negative"><?php echo $this->__('Negative') ;?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add  description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

if the seller's products is distinct from other products then you can use one to many relationship

One to many relationship goes like

Each seller may have zero, one or multiple products. But an product can belong to only one seller

For example 
You a have seller called jack he has 4 products on the products table 
You will create a foreign key linking to table products using jack's id on sellers table

notice: if you deleted jack from sellers table all his products will be deleted too and it makes sense you can't supply a merchat a product that his seller doesn't exist

Here is an answer that will help you [One-to-Many relationship in MySQL - how to build model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044792/one-to-many-relationship-in-mysql-how-to-build-model)